# error with using toType when where is in use

Tags: javascript, breeze

I am getting error when the following code runs:

```js
let em = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost/api');
let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer').where('State', '==', 'co').toType('Customer');  //error
em.executeQuery(query)
  .then(data => {
    //do something with data
  })
  .catch(error => {
   //error handling
  });
```

> Error: The left hand side of a binary predicate cannot be a literal expression, it must be a valid property or functional predicate expression: State

So I change the code above to like below, but I still get the same error:

```js
let em = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost/api');
let condition = breeze.Predicate.create('State', '==', 'co'); //added predicate
let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer').where(condition).toType('Customer');  //error
em.executeQuery(query)
  .then(data => {
    //do something with data
  })
  .catch(error => {
   //error handling
  });
```

But the following just works fine if toType is not used:

```js
let em = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost/api');
let condition = breeze.Predicate.create('State', '==', 'co');
let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer').where(condition);  //works without toType
em.executeQuery(query)
  .then(data => {
    //do something with data
  })
  .catch(error => {
   //error handling
  });
```

Please advise how I can fix it.

Comment: I still can't figure out why it's not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not populate your meta data correctly. Please make sure you have fetchMetadata executed correctly before using predicates its looking for fields that it cannot find in meta data - most likely.

```
let em = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost/api'); 
em.fetchMetadata().then(() => {

// execute your query here.


   let condition = breeze.Predicate.create('State', '==', 'co'); //added predicate
   let query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customer').where(condition).toType('Customer');  //error
   em.executeQuery(query)
      .then(data => {
    //do something with data
    })
      .catch(error => {
   //error handling
   });
```

})

Also note that you could be getting this if State or Customer are not in the right "case". You might have specified camelCase as an option? then the field should be state and not State etc.